# Forbidden Island Engineer's power?

Tags: forbidden-island

In Forbidden Island, must the Engineer be either on or adjacent to a tile to shore it up?

Answer (score 8):

From the manual:

[image]

Any character can shore up a tile that is either adjacent or underneath them. The engineer is listed as an exception because he can shore up 2 tiles per action. It doesn't indicate any other requirements or exceptions for the Engineer. It does distinctly say they must be for one action so you can't spread it around.

Some think that you can shore up two tiles away:

> The group I played with argued that he could shore up two tiles in a straight "line". That is, one adjacent tile plus the one next in line, adjacent to that adjacent tile. So, shoring up a tile that has a tile between it and the tile he/she is standing on.

but the general consensus is this is incorrect. Nothing in the rules indicate that. The ability doesn't say he can shore up two adjacent tiles but 2 tiles which inherit the previous property of adjacent to the player.

Comment: Re "*Nothing in the rules indicate that*", Actually, that's exactly what the rules indicate. The Engineer's ability reads "shore up two tiles for one action", and the shore action is defined as follows: "To shore a tile, simply flip it so its un-flooded side is facing up". As written, the rules place no limit on which tiles the Engineer can shore up. Only the ability available to everyone has such as limit specified. But as you said, that's not the intended reading. The Engineer is only meant to be able to shore up his tile and orthogonally adjacent tiles.

Comment: I still disagree that the rules indicate that shoring up two tiles indicates t hat these tiles might be any two tiles. It doesn't for instance say "Shore up any 2 tiles" the way the sandbag does say "Shore up any one tile on the island" clearly stating that the tile doesn't need to follow the indicated rules. I believe in the absence of new rules the old rules are clearly and obviously intended thus the lacking of other exceptions means the Engineering tile doesn't imply more exceptions than it explicitly details.

Comment: also you indicate _the shore action is defined as follows_ and then use only half the definition. Part of the definition of shore up action is that it only applies to adjacent tiles. It's actually the more important half of the definition as it pertains to this discussion. Shoring up is defined as something you do to adjacent tiles.

Comment: The indicated rules, as you call them, don't mention the word "adjacent" at all.

Comment: It's in the first sentence of the image I linked originally - https://i.imgur.com/w3uETri.png - You may for 1 or more actions, show up any ADJACENT Island tile - it then goes on to define specifically which five tiles are eligible for shoring up.

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't say the word "adjacent" doesn't appear in the rules.

Comment: but this is the rule on shoring up. This is what we're talking about. You say the rules for shoring up don't mention adjacent and I'm saying it does. Is there a wire being crossed here?

Comment: There are two abilities here. One described in the first sentence of the image (shore up 1 adjacent tile for 1 action), and one described on the Engineer (shore up 2 tiles for 1 action). We're not talking about the first ability. The definition of shoring up is "To shore a tile, simply flip it so its un-flooded side is facing up". There's no mention of "adjacent" at all. The answer lies outside the rules. That's why you had to mention the general consensus.

Comment: @ikegami I know I am late to the party but I disagree - this is not describing separate abilities but providing an exception, a modification, to one ability based on the character, as is made clear by the rule book calling it an exception - so it changes the relevant part of the general rule where it says tile to "(up to) 2 tiles" with the rest entirely unchanged, including the restriction to adjacent tiles. The answer is definitely within the rules.

Comment: @Andrew, How is "You may shore up any 1 adjacent Island tile" and "You may shore up 2 tiles" the same ability/instruction? Yes, they provide a modification to shoring up (which is defined as "flipping a tile so its un-flooded side is face up"). Both of them do. I do agree that the adjacency requirement is *meant to* apply to both, but it's only specified for one *as written*. That's all I said.

Comment: @ikegami The basic ability is "you may for 1 or more actions, shore up any adjacent tile, or the Island tile your pawn is on [...]" The engineer has an exception that modifies that basic ability to "you may for 1 or more actions, shore up 2 of any adjacent tile, or the Island tile your pawn is on [...]" or however you want to word the modification of the same ability. Just like explorer "you may for 1 or more actions, shore up any adjacent tile, diagonal tile, or the Island tile your pawn is on [...]" Exceptions modify relevant sections of the base rule, not replace the whole thing.

Comment: @Andrew Re "*The basic ability is ...*" That's not what the rules say. The rules *explicitly* say that that to shore up is to *simply* flip it over so its un-flooded side is facing up. See the image in the answer to which this is a comment. Anything else is a modification to shoring up.

Comment: There is an image of the very rule I quoted from in the answer. The exception for Engineer modifies how many tiles it applies to only, the exception for Explorer modifies which tiles may be selected. You are ignoring the first half of the rule, the player action and focusing exclusively on the physical result of taking that action as if it were the entire ability text.

Comment: @Andrew Re "*You are ignoring the first half of the rule*", No, The definition given for shoring up is "simply flip it over so its un-flooded side is facing up". I'm not ignoring an part of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105992/discussion-between-andrew-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

---

The question is understandable.

The Engineer's ability reads "shore up two tiles for one action", and the shore action is defined as follows: "To shore a tile, simply flip it so its un-flooded side is facing up". As written, the rules place no limit on which tiles the Engineer can shore up.

But then one considers that other players are restricted to shoring up adjacent tiles. "You may, for one or more actions, shore up any adjacent tile (up, down, left, right) or the Island tile your pawn is on", and one might think this restriction is suppose to apply to the Engineer as well.

They'd be right. The restriction does apply to the Engineer as well.

---

Compare the Engineer's and the Explorer's ability.

The Explorer considers *diagonal* tiles to also be adjacent for shoring and movement purposes.

The more restrictive reading of the Engineer's ability gives it a free action almost every turn. This is a huge boon. It would be insane to also give it a power that's much more powerful than the Explorer's (considering *all* tiles to be adjacent for shoring purposes).

---

The [same answer](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/580940/engineer-and-shoring) was previously given on Board Game Geek.